# Is there some kind of global hash for "Locales" strings in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We use devise and have this file `config/locales/devise.en.yml`. It contains a YAML map of strings, for example:

```
en:
  devise:
    confirmations:
      confirmed: "Your account was successfully confirmed."
```

If I wanted to access this "confirmed" string from some arbitrary place in the application, how would I do it?

For example, something like the following pseudocode:

```
msg = Rails.locales.en.devise.confirmations.confirmed
```

I suppose I could do `YAML.parse` and store the map in memory, but I wonder if Rails is already doing this somewhere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`I18n.t`](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#looking-up-translations) method:

```
I18n.t('devise.confirmations.confirmed')
```

It's available as a helper in views, so there you can just use:

```
t('devise.confirmations.confirmed')
```